# How do I append a variable from a function into a list while looping code in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, append

I'm using Python 3 tp scrape price data from a website which results in a variable I named "price". I want to append that data variable into a list I named "pricelist". After the variable is appended into my list, the code needs to repeat the function section of the code to scrape the website again and append the new variable to the end of list. This needs to happen over and over again. Here is my code for this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

pricelist = []
i = 1
while i == 1:

    def main():
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get('https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Low-Back-Computer-Chair-Black/dp/B01D7P5BFS/ref=sxin_4_pb?keywords=chair&pd_rd_i=B01D7P5BFS&pd_rd_r=3a3a009f-5d5c-44e0-ab99-a1c3b041e862&pd_rd_w=SNQnR&pd_rd_wg=MBlCg&pf_rd_p=f427576c-4cd9-4023-b007-842b60ea2d8a&pf_rd_r=TPZ7QCF875D9HG3S2KA9&qid=1575473754')
        time.sleep(3)
        price = browser.find_element_by_id('priceblock_ourprice')
        price = price.text
        browser.close()
    main()

pricelist.append(price)
print(pricelist)

restart = "yes"
if restart == "yes":
    main()
```

The above code repeats the scraping just fine with no errors but it does not print the list or append to the list. If the variable from the function is "$49.99", I want the `print(pricelist)` command to output:

```
$49.99 #first run through of code
$49.99, $49.99 #second run through of code
$49.99, $49.99, $49.99 #third run through of code
$49.99, $49.99, $49.99, $49.99 #fourth run through of code
#repeat this appending over and over again for as long as I need
```

How do I accomplish this in Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code runs into an infinite loop

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

pricelist = []
i = 1
while i == 1:

    def main():
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get('https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Low-Back-Computer-Chair-Black/dp/B01D7P5BFS/ref=sxin_4_pb?keywords=chair&pd_rd_i=B01D7P5BFS&pd_rd_r=3a3a009f-5d5c-44e0-ab99-a1c3b041e862&pd_rd_w=SNQnR&pd_rd_wg=MBlCg&pf_rd_p=f427576c-4cd9-4023-b007-842b60ea2d8a&pf_rd_r=TPZ7QCF875D9HG3S2KA9&qid=1575473754')
        time.sleep(3)
        price = browser.find_element_by_id('priceblock_ourprice')
        price = price.text
        browser.close()
    main()
```

and the following code won't be running / your program control never reaches

```
pricelist.append(price)
print(pricelist)

restart = "yes"
if restart == "yes":
    main()
```

Since the written code is in python - python blocks are decided by code indentation.

mode your code as following

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver



def fun():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Low-Back-Computer-Chair-Black/dp/B01D7P5BFS/ref=sxin_4_pb?keywords=chair&pd_rd_i=B01D7P5BFS&pd_rd_r=3a3a009f-5d5c-44e0-ab99-a1c3b041e862&pd_rd_w=SNQnR&pd_rd_wg=MBlCg&pf_rd_p=f427576c-4cd9-4023-b007-842b60ea2d8a&pf_rd_r=TPZ7QCF875D9HG3S2KA9&qid=1575473754')
    time.sleep(3)
    price = browser.find_element_by_id('priceblock_ourprice')
    price = price.text
    browser.close()
    return price


pricelist = []
i = 1
while i == 1:
    pricelist.append(fun())
    print(pricelist)
```

Comment: This results in an error of   File "C:/Users/Marshall/Desktop/scraper/looping.py", ```line 8
    def main():
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block```

Comment: change the function name to something else.

Comment: you can define your function outside of the while block

Comment: Surapruram it just gave me this error: `line 19, in <module>
    pricelist.append(price)
NameError: name 'price' is not defined'`

Comment: you can use return statement to return objects form the function

Comment: I got it to work by indenting `global price` right under `def fun()`. I read somewhere that you shouldn't use the global though...is this correct?

Comment: as Software Development Practice its not good to use global variables. they are not reliable ( since any module can access it)

Comment: can you mark it as answer so that it will help others who land on same issue

Answer (score 0):

Take def main() outside the while loop. You don't have to define it every time.

Second make your main() return **price**. Then assign it to variable

```
a = main()
pricelist.append(a)
```

And *while i == 1* is not neccessary, if you have to you can just type *while True*

But i don't reccomend using while True without any break option.

You can add **try except** block with such except:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
```

the block:

```
restart = 'yes'
if restart == 'yes:
    main()
```

can be replaced with more common:

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

Which will be True if this script is executed and not imported

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python and coding in general so I don't know what you mean about taking def main() outside the while loop? I also don't know how to make main() return a price. I did a Google search of "return" for Python and sort of see what that means, but don't fully understand how to do it. Any advice?